# colorbox mouseout mouseleave

Tags: jquery, mouseover, colorbox, mouseout

I am using colobox and would like to have the it close automatically when you mouseout of the photos.

I found this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185649/jquery-hover-for-colorbox-image-collection-overlay) which works great for the mouseover... but I don't want to click to close.

I setup a basic jsfiddle here. Any help would be appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/peu8y/

**UPDATE** I changed the div for the mouseleave (see the demo below) and it now works.

http://jsfiddle.net/peu8y/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).colorbox.close();`

Refer this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/peu8y/1/), it works but it see triggering more than one time.

Comment: how would that work with the mouseout based on this example: http://jsfiddle.net/peu8y/

Comment: @digitalbart: I have updated the example, it works but i can see there is some triggering happening more than one time. That one am unable to figure out.

Comment: thanks for the example that makes sense, I will take a look and see if I can figure anything out.